# Re-render web-view on bottomTabNavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview

How I can re-render a web-view running inside a app built with react native. For exemple: The cart tab need to load the same url every time I click on it.

This is the cart class:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, WebView, View, Button, ScrollView,
  RefreshControl,
  Text, } from 'react-native';
import Config from '../config';



export default class CarrinhoScreen extends React.Component {

  reload() {
    this.myWebView.reload()
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <WebView
            source={{ uri: 'https://www.genieshopp.com/checkout/cart/' }}
            userAgent='bring-app'
            startInLoadingState={true}
            ref={(ref) => this.myWebView = ref}
          />
        </View>
    </>
    )
  }
};
```

Here is where the tabNavigator is created:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import CarrinhoScreen from '../screens/CarrinhoScreen';

const config = Platform.select({
  web: { headerMode: 'screen' },
  default: {},
});

const CarrinhoStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Carrinho: CarrinhoScreen
  },
  config
);

CarrinhoStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Carrinho',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon focused={focused} name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios-cart' : 'md-cart'}/>
  ),
};

CarrinhoStack.path = '';

const tabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
{
  CarrinhoStack,
  },
  {
    backBehavior: 'history'
  }
);

tabNavigator.path = '';

export default tabNavigator;
```

I know there is the myWebView.reload(), but I want to know how I reload it when the bottom tab is switched or when I click on the same icon.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by putting `resetOnBlur: CarrinhoScreen` after `backBehavior: history`
You can put any other screen you want to reset on there.

Answer (score 0):

have you found the solution for this? I have used useFocus in tabbed navigation, else you can use InjectJavascript and reload on every render

```
useFocusEffect(
React.useCallback(() => {
  if (webViewRef.current) {
    webViewRef.current.reload();
  }
  return () => {};
}, [])
```

);

if you want to go to any specific url

```
const webViewRef = useRef(null);
const baseUrl = "https://facebook.com";

useFocusEffect(
 React.useCallback(() => {
   if (webViewRef.current) {
    // Navigate to the base URL and reload 
    the WebView
    const script = `window.location = '${baseUrl}'; true;`;
    webViewRef.current.injectJavaScript(script);
  }
  // Cleanup function is not required in this case
  return () => {};
}, [])
);
```

this is not the exact code but this will help you out